# Need help on a simple Java assignment prompt

Tags: java

I've done multiple assignments for intro Java so far, but I need some help understanding what this [prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX0oN.png) is asking me to do.

> #### Minimum requirements:
>
> - Create a separate class that contains the following methods (4 points) *Note:* this class should be separate and apart from the
>     public class that holds the main method.  You can either make a class
>     that is *not* a public class or you could put it in a separate .java
>     file:
>
>   - A method that will accept *a parameter as an integer array for the phone number* and *a parameter for the security code* (you choose
>       the data type for the security code).  Use one (or more) repatriation
>       structures to replace each number in the array with its encrypted
>       version using **C = (P + key) mod 10** with the appropriate digit in
>       the security code as described above. Note: You should make the
>       replacement *in the original array. (5 points)
>   - Create a method that will accept an encrypted phone number *as an integer array* and decoding key.  Use one (or more) reputation
>       structures to return it to its plain text (decrypted) version using
>       **P = (C - key) mod 10 and the conditional**
>
>     - `if (P < 0) P = P + 10`
>   - Note: You should make the replacement *in the original array. (5 points)
> - call the method in the main method with at least one sample phone number.  Display the phone number in the main before and after calling
>     each method (5 points).
>
> *Important Note:* You can get the phone number from the user at the console or with a GUI if you prefer to do that, but it is not
>   required.  You can put the phone number in the code when you create
>   the array instead if you would rather do it that way.  Regardless of
>   how you get the phone number, it must be put in an array and the array
>   must be passed to another method that accepts an array as a parameter.
>   You should *not* get the phone number and prices it in the same
>   method.

Also, I need some tips on how to go about on this. I started with:

```
public class Encrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {6, 5, 0, 7, 8, 7, 9, 9, 0, 9};
        cipher cipher = new cipher();
        cipher.yes(a, 1, 2, 3);
    }
}

class cipher {

    public void yes(int[] phone, int x, int y, int z) {
        for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
            //Don't know what to do here, I want to try the security codes I set to the array slots but I'm not sure how. I started with phone = (phone + x) % 10 but I keep getting an error.
            // I'm having a hard time understanding this assignment and working with the arrays, if possible could I get some kind of walk through or tips?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be more specific. What exactly are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Edit your question to show exactly what error `phone = (phone + x) % 10` is giving you.  We specialize in troubleshooting bugs not walkthroughs.

Comment: You shouldn't be asking for assigments complete solutions. At least try first by yourself!

Comment: OP did *not* ask for complete solutions. He asked for tips and maybe a *walkthrough*. Big difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: don't use *private classes*. Although it is possible to do so, you should always create a separate file for each class (everything else is nonsense because you wouldn't be able to reuse the private class anywhere else)

Secondly:  class names should start with a capital letter (while variables start with a small letter). like this:

```
public class Cipher{
   ....
}
```

Then you can create an instance of that class like this:

```
Cipher cipher = new Cipher();  // here Cipher is the class and cipher is the name of your variable
```

Now, as I understand it they are asking you to transform the phone number digit wise with this calculation:   `C= (P+key) %10`

So in your method you could do something like this:

```
public void yes(int[] phone, int x, int y, int z) {
    int code = x+y+z; // I don't know how you constructed your code but lets say it is a code of 3 digits x,y,z that give the number xyz (e.g. 1,2,3 -> 123)
    for (int count = 0; count < phone.length; count++) {  // you need to iterate through the complete phone number. Which means that your loop starts at 0 and stops when reaching the end (length) of your phone array
        phone[count] = (your calculation here) // you replace each digit from the phone array by the result of that calculation
    }
}
```

If for example your phone array looks like this:

```
 int[] phone = {4,5,6,4,6,8};
```

you can access each element from the array by the index of the digit:

```
phone[0]  // 4
phone[1]  // 5
phone[4]  // there you have the 5th element of the array which is 6
```

! important: the index starts **always** at `0` and ends at `array.length -1` (in this case `6-1 = 5`)

so. `int digit= phone[0];` will return the first element of the array and put it in the new varable `digit`. In order to write something into the array you would do something like this: `phone[0] = 3;` It says that you replace the first element of the array with the number `3`.

And this is what you need to do (I showed you in the example). You need to write the result of the  `C= (P+key) %10` calculation into the array.

So once more your assignment:

- You loop through the array `for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){...`  (here `i` is the index, in your code you called it `count`
- you get the digit from the array at the current index `int digit = array[i];`
- you do the calculation: `int result = (digit + code)%10;`
- you put the result back into the array: `array[i] = result;`

Don't get confused with the variable names here, I did it on purpose, because they are only names :)

Answer (score 2):

You tried to use an array as if it was a value it holds. I suggest you to read about arrays before tackling that assingment, the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) is a good place to start.

After understanding arrays properly, you will learn that you need to specify and index to access the array values, like `phone[0]` (this will get the first value on the phone array).
That assignment asks you to basically iterate through the array and apply the formula to each element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create class other than the class main method resides and create the methods asked in the question. You need to pass a int array to the methods and another int which acts as key. I have done the question. put those classes in to different files or same file.
**Main class**

```
public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Cipher cipher=new Cipher();
        int[] in={2,3,4,5,6};
        cipher.encrypt(in,2);
        cipher.decrypt(in,2);
        int n = in.length;
        for (int x=0;x<n;x++){
          System.out.println(in[x]);
        }
      } 
    }
```

**Cipher class**

```
class Cipher{
  public void encrypt(int[] in, int key){
    int n = in.length;
    for (int x=0;x<n;x++){
      in[x]=(in[x]+key)%10;
    }
  }

  public void decrypt(int[] in, int key){
    int n = in.length;
    for (int x=0;x<n;x++){
      in[x]=(in[x]-key)%10;
      if(in[x]<0){
        in[x]=in[x]+10;
      }
    }
  }
```

}